# Laravel Repository/Service Pattern: How to handle Auth and Gates

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

I'm starting to use repository and service pattern for my laravel project.

Just a quick background, I use repository as the data mapper and service to help keeping up controllers do their main job which is, receiving requests and sending out responses, and thus be thinner.

Following code sample is to give you some idea about above explanation:

```php
// App\Repositories\Eloquent\UsersRepository
class UsersRepository implements UsersRepoInterface {
    protected $model;

    public function __construct (Model $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function all() : Collection {
        //
    }
    public function find($id) : Model {
        //
    }
    // and all other methods ...
}

// App\Services\UserService
class UserService {
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct (UsersRepoInterface $user_repo) {
        $this->repo = $user;
    }
    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return User
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function create(array $data) : User {
        // All business logics to create a user data
        return $user;
    }
    // and all other methods ...
}

// App\Http\Controllers\UserController
class UserController extends Controller {
    private $user;

    public function __construct (UserService $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function create (Request $request) : Response {
        $user = $this->user->create($request->all());

        return response(['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

Also, my project is an internal API app, thus an authentication is needed to make most of the requests. I use OAuth2.0 from Laravel Passport.

#### The Question

Before I switched over to repository/service or what-sort-you-called pattern, I used Gates and Policies before the requests are passed to the controller methods. And obviously User Auth is passed to every policy method which I don't feel right as the Auth (which is from Passport), I believe use User Model directly instead which is then a violation for repository pattern, isn't it?

Therefore, I really need some advice how am I supposed to manage resolving such problem ?

Any suggestion and obviously help are really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Policies require user authentication but delegate that authentication to the gate. In your case the gate would be passport so there's no extra layer there. I don't see how the repository pattern changes any of this since that's just an additional layer over the Laravel models which are a different level of abstraction from authentication/authorisation.

Comment: Sorry but maybe I misunderstood what you are saying. Are you saying policies don't require user authentication? If so, yes you are right. Sorry if my sentence up there from the question confused you. But anyway, I'm saying all my policies require user auth to check whether given user has the permission to do given request. Laravel automatically injected User model to the callback function of each policy method which I don't feel that's a right thing for repository pattern, don't you think so? I don't know how do I change the parameter to use UserService which I feel more appropriate @apokryfos

Comment: User policies do *require* authentication but do not *perform* authentication. That is done by the guard which in your case is passport. That would not change with this code. The user injection comes from the guard and whatever method the guard uses to get the user. Passport probably just gets it from the bearer token

Comment: Okay I got it. Then my question is, am I supposed to change the authentication layer to use the repo instead? In that case, I need to change the passport, right? Because I believe passport use User model instead to authenticate which I think is a violation to repo pattern. Or do you have any suggestion to keep using passport in repo pattern @apokryfos ?

Comment: Passport (all guards really) use a `UserProvider` implementation that you can specify in the configuration so you would need to write your own user provider which uses the repository rather than the default Laravel one which uses activerecord. [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) have more details on how

Comment: Okay I think I got some idea from that. Thanks!